# Just print the last line of a array c#

Tags: c#

This code is just saving the last line of my string array. I want to save all lines of matricula_conc in a text file (txt).

I don't know what to do, how could I fix it? Anyone know?

```
class DesafioPuc
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {      

      foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("matriculasSemDV.txt"))
        {

          int m_1 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(0, 1)); //1st digit
          int m_2 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(1, 1)); //2nd digit
          int m_3 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(2, 1)); //3rd digit
          int m_4 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(3, 1)); //4th digit

          int mult_m1 = m_1 * 5; 
          int mult_m2 = m_2 * 4;
          int mult_m3 = m_3 * 3;
          int mult_m4 = m_4 * 2;

          int final_sum = mult_m1 + mult_m2 + mult_m3 + mult_m4;

          int rest_div = final_sum % 16;

          string rest_div_hex = rest_div.ToString("X");

          string matricula_conc = line + "-" + rest_div_hex;

          string[] b = {matricula_conc};


          string path = "matriculasComDV.txt";
          File.WriteAllLines(path, b, Encoding.UTF8);             


        }      

    }
}
```

Comment: `string[] b = {matricula_conc};` should be a `List<string>` declared **before** the loop (and then `Add` to it **inside** the loop). `File.WriteAllLines(path, b, Encoding.UTF8);` should be done **after** the loop.

Comment: Try using File.AppendAllText instead of File.WriteAllLines. You will need to recreate the file before the loop, so a new file is created on every run.

Comment: What's the problem... Just use `File.AppendAllLines()` and its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx) method, Creates a new file, writes the specified string array to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten. That is why you get only the last line printed in the file. Instead of `File.WriteAllLines(path, b, Encoding.UTF8);` use `File.AppendAllLines(path, b, Encoding.UTF8);` in the above code to get all lines printed. But the best way to do this is by using a list like the following:

```
List<string> LinesToWrite = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("matriculasSemDV.txt"))
{
     // Your logic here
     string rest_div_hex = rest_div.ToString("X");
     string matricula_conc = line + "-" + rest_div_hex;
     LinesToWrite.Add(matricula_conc);
}
string path = "matriculasComDV.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(path, LinesToWrite , Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: You suggestion is correct, but requires more memory than what is actually needed (saving all strings in a list). It is better to simply save to disk without storing in memory if it is not needed

Comment: @YanivShaked: Suppose I have 1500 lines in the source files(`matriculasSemDV.txt`) then I need to call `AppendAllLines` 1500 times. I think its better to keep the collection in memory and write once instead for `1500` subsequent  IO operations. That's why suggested this approach

Comment: You are correct. The problem with your approach exists only if you have an enormous number of lines (for example, 10G lines). In this case, memory consumption of your approach will be a constraint.

Comment: @YanivShaked: ok Agreed, then which one you suggested in that situation of `10GB` Text file?

Comment: Probably go for a hybrid solution: Generate few MBs of text in memory and write to disk (preferably asynchronous IO operation)

Comment: @YanivShaked: I think you are making thing complecated

Comment: @YanivShaked it's very simple to use C#'s Stream operations to read/write individual lines without the overhead of keeping neither input nor output in memory. See the example I posted.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Agree, your example presents the best solution, no memory overhead

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a stream to read/write the individual lines to avoid keeping everything in memory.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("matriculasComDV.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
using (var reader = new StreamReader("matriculasSemDV.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line = null;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int m_1 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(0, 1)); //1st digit
        int m_2 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(1, 1)); //2nd digit
        int m_3 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(2, 1)); //3rd digit
        int m_4 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(3, 1)); //4th digit

        int mult_m1 = m_1 * 5;
        int mult_m2 = m_2 * 4;
        int mult_m3 = m_3 * 3;
        int mult_m4 = m_4 * 2;

        int final_sum = mult_m1 + mult_m2 + mult_m3 + mult_m4;
        int rest_div = final_sum % 16;

        writer.WriteLine("{0} - {1:X}", line, rest_div);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve the problem. But thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Below is what I used.

```
class DesafioPuc
            {
                public static void Main(string[] args)
                {      

                  Console.WriteLine("-----matriculasComDV-----"); //Print em tela do nome_arquivo matriculasComDV.txt (meramente ilustrativo)

                  foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("matriculasSemDV.txt"))
                    {

                      int m_1 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(0, 1)); //1st digits array
                      int m_2 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(1, 1)); //2nd digits array
                      int m_3 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(2, 1)); //3rd digits array
                      int m_4 = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(3, 1)); //4th digits array

                      int mult_m1 = m_1 * 5; //Multiplica o vetor de 1st digits por 5
                      int mult_m2 = m_2 * 4; //Multiplica o vetor de 2nd digits por 4
                      int mult_m3 = m_3 * 3; //Multiplica o vetor de 3rd digits por 3
                      int mult_m4 = m_4 * 2; //Multiplica o vetor de 4th digits por 2

                      int final_sum = mult_m1 + mult_m2 + mult_m3 + mult_m4; //soma os vetores dos digitos a fim de calcular o total

                      int rest_div = final_sum % 16; //resto da divisão do vetor final_sum por 16

                      string rest_div_hex = rest_div.ToString("X"); //converte o vetor resto de decimal para hexadecimal

                      string matricula_conc = line + "-" + rest_div_hex; //concatena linha a linha o vetor matriculasSemDV com "-" e o resto da divisao em hexadecimal

                      File.AppendAllText("matriculasComDV.txt", matricula_conc + Environment.NewLine); //salva o vetor concatenado

                      Console.WriteLine(matricula_conc); //print em tela do arquivo matriculasComDV.txt concatenado (meramente ilustrativo)

                    }      


                  Console.WriteLine("-----matriculasVerificadas-----"); //Print em tela do nome_arquivo matriculasVerificadas.txt (meramente ilustrativo)

                  string matriculasComDV = File.ReadAllText("matriculasComDV.txt"); //atribui o arquivo matriculasComDV gerado acima para um vetor de string

                  foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("matriculasParaVerificar.txt")) //para cada linha no vetor matriculasParaVerificar, faça:
                  {
                    if (line.Contains(matriculasComDV)) //compara linha a linha se o vetor matriculasParaVerificar contém alguma stringo do vetor matriculasComDV
                    {
                      string concatena_verdadeiro = line + " verdadeiro"; //concatena as linhas do vetor matriculasParaVerificar com o devido indicador 
                      Console.WriteLine(concatena_verdadeiro); //print em tela do vetor caso a condição seja satisfeita (meramente ilustrativo)
                      File.AppendAllText("matriculasVerificadas.txt", concatena_verdadeiro + Environment.NewLine); //salva o arquivo concatenado em matriculasVerificadas.txt
                    }  
                    else //senão...
                    {
                      string concatena_falso = line + " falso"; //concatena as linhas do vetor matriculasParaVerificar com o devido indicador
                      Console.WriteLine(concatena_falso); //print em tela do vetor caso a condição seja satisfeita (meramente ilustrativo)
                      File.AppendAllText("matriculasVerificadas.txt", concatena_falso + Environment.NewLine); //salva o arquivo concatenado em matriculasVerificadas.txt
                    }
                  }

                }
            }
```